# Use lambda to filter Reader

Tags: java

I'm reading lines from a zipped input stream, and I need to filter it by the first 4 positions (a period). Is is possible to use a lambda (like the filter in streams) to avoid the condition?

```
private List<String> readlinesByPeriod(DPeriod period, ZipInputStream zis) throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList();

    byte[] data = SCIOUtils.readData(zis);
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, CharEncoding.ISO_8859_1));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String periodCode = StringUtils.substring(line, 0, 4);
        if (periodCode.equals(period.getCode())) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
    }

    return lines;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible

```
return reader.lines()
    .filter(line -> StringUtils.substring(line, 0, 4).equals(period.getCode()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It's worth noting that [the JavaDoc for `BufferedReader.lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--) says

> If an IOException is thrown when accessing the underlying
> BufferedReader, **it is wrapped in an UncheckedIOException** which will be
> thrown from the Stream method that caused the read to take place

So if you want your method to continue to throw a checked exception (IOException or otherwise), then you'd have to wrap the above in a try-catch block for `UncheckedIOException` and wrap it and rethrow as a checked exception.

Comment: I found that BufferedReader has a lines method which returns a Stream, I used:  return reader.lines()
    .filter(line -> line.startsWith(period.getCode()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: @LluisMartinez Oh, good find. I learned something today. I didn't think they'd bothered to retrospectively add stream support to classes like BufferedReader. Updated my answer